# Getting partial data from socket in communication between C# and python

Tags: c#, python, sockets, partial

I'm sending some data from a python process to a C# application, but for some reason, that I can't seem to find out, not all of the data gets to C#.
My receive code is:

```
  byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
  int recv = reciever.Receive(buf);
  string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, recv);
  while (data.IndexOf("<E\0O\0F>") > -1)
  {
        buf = new byte[1024];
        recv = reciever.Receive(buf);
        data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, recv);
  }
```

have I don't anything wrong? (From python I'm sending as usual using socket.send)
Here is the code in python that is sending the data:

```
gui_socket.send('RefreshProcesses&' + processes + "<EOF>")
```

Comment: "not all of the data" - So, what part of the data is missing?

Comment: Do you flush/close the socket when done sending?

Comment: @HannoBinder i get 1007 chars out of about 1900, I don't close the socket when done sending because I need it to stay open for further sending. The loop stops at somepoint so I guess this part works fine... (The <EOF>, by the way, why do I need to add the \0? it just didn't work without it so I add this, in python i send <EOF> with the null chars)

Comment: Re `\0`: The issue may lie in `Encoding.ASCII`. What's the encoding the python side is using when sending a string?

Comment: Did you try [sendall()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendall)?

Comment: Its very confusing you say python but show c# code. If you are writing code twice you are doing something wrong. I see the same code inside the loop and outside the loop. You need to check the value of recv do see if the socket has closed which is probably an issue you haven't come across yet. Show us your code in python that is sending.

Comment: @HannoBinder I have, but it didn't work.

Comment: @WalterM Edited my post with the python code. (and the title to clarify)